# what is the server_key in php memcached?

Tags: php, memcached

php document discription and example:

`public array Memcached::getServerByKey ( string $server_key )`

```
<?php 
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('mem1.domain.com', 11211, 33);
$m->addServer('mem2.domain.com', 11211, 67);
?>
```

I cannot find the server_key param.
**where is the server_key?**

how to use ***bykey functions?

```
Memcached::addByKey()
Memcached::deleteByKey()
Memcached::getServerByKey()
...
```

Comment: Did you look at the example in the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.getserverbykey.php#111800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.getserverbykey.php:

> **server_key**
>
> The key identifying the server to store the value on or
>   retrieve it from. Instead of hashing on the actual key for the item,
>   we hash on the server key when deciding which memcached server to talk
>   to. This allows related items to be grouped together on a single
>   server for efficiency with multi operations.

Normally, the memcached server is chosen based on the key you're storing (e.g. `Memcached::add("key", "value")` chooses which server to use based on `"key"`). By specifying a server key, you can change which server is chosen.

So it's something *you* provide if you want to group values by some means other than the key you're storing or looking up.